# My iframe doesn't trim properly

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've tried everything but my iframe just doesn't trim! Here's my code:

```
<div id="hljod">
<iframe src="http://www.ruv.is/hvad-er-malid/enginn-medaljon-jonsson" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="posistion:absoulute;clip:rect(171px,1100px,800px,250px); top:-171;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Its `position:absolute`.Correct it.

Comment: And what do you mean by trim??

Comment: Take the nav of to display only the content.

Comment: And I corrected it but it still doesn't work!

Comment: So you want to hide the navigation bar and display only the content?